# how to get value of a json from a json object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How to get a value from jsonstring.I have stringified json as

```
[{"id":0,"date":"05-11-2018","total":0},{"id":1,"date":"06-11-2018","total":0},{"id":2,"date":"07-11-2018","total":0},{"id":3,"date":"08-11-2018","total":0},{"id":4,"date":"09-11-2018","total":0},{"id":5,"date":"10-11-2018","total":0},{"id":6,"date":"11-11-2018","total":0}]
```

---

How to get the second date 06-11-2018 from this javascript object string.

```
var counter = 0;
var jsonObj;
var stringify, obj;

function myFunction(con) {
  counter = con + counter;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/driverapp/www/c11/week.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      counter: counter
    },
    success: function(response) {
      jsonObj = JSON.stringify(response);
    }
  });
  alert(jsonObj);
}
```

Comment: add alert(response[1]['date']); inside success

Comment: No need to `stringify` your `response` it is a `json` array so you can use it in a `loop` or call individual value like `response[1].date`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var json=[{"id":0,"date":"05-11-2018","total":0},{"id":1,"date":"06-11-2018","total":0},{"id":2,"date":"07-11-2018","total":0},{"id":3,"date":"08-11-2018","total":0},{"id":4,"date":"09-11-2018","total":0},{"id":5,"date":"10-11-2018","total":0},{"id":6,"date":"11-11-2018","total":0}];

for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[i];
    console.log(obj.date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json object by using their key value.
to get value from this object

```
for(var i in response ) {
    // to print only date from every object
    console.log(response[i].date)
}
```

and also your response is an json array so get second object by

```
response[1].date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet after AJAX sucess.

```js
// after AJAX sucess you will get JSON in string format

// parse STRING -> JSON object

var response = '[{"id":0,"date":"05-11-2018","total":0},{"id":1,"date":"06-11-2018","total":0},{"id":2,"date":"07-11-2018","total":0},{"id":3,"date":"08-11-2018","total":0},{"id":4,"date":"09-11-2018","total":0},{"id":5,"date":"10-11-2018","total":0},{"id":6,"date":"11-11-2018","total":0}]';

var json = JSON.parse(response);

// loop JSON object to get date

json.forEach(function(obj){ 
   console.log('date : ', obj.date );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .filter()

```
var x = [{"id":0,"date":"05-11-2018","total":0}, {"id":1,"date":"06-11-2018","total":0},{"id":2,"date":"07-11-2018","total":0},{"id":3,"date":"08-11-2018","total":0},{"id":4,"date":"09-11-2018","total":0},{"id":5,"date":"10-11-2018","total":0},{"id":6,"date":"11-11-2018","total":0}];
 function getDate(num){
     var n=num;
     var d=x.filter((el,i)=>{
          if ( i==n)
          return el;
     });
     return d[0].date;
 };
 console.log(getDate(2)); // 07-11-2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will iterate all items from json

```js
    var json=[{"id":0,"date":"05-11-2018","total":0},{"id":1,"date":"06-11-2018","total":0},{"id":2,"date":"07-11-2018","total":0},{"id":3,"date":"08-11-2018","total":0},{"id":4,"date":"09-11-2018","total":0},{"id":5,"date":"10-11-2018","total":0},{"id":6,"date":"11-11-2018","total":0}];

json.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.id + ' ' + item.date + ' ' + item.total );
});
```